# After send webhook of parse push notification

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push-notification

Is it possible to setup a web hook for anytime a push notification is sent via Parse?

I want to retrieve the details of the push notification and set a column against any devices the push notification was sent to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hook that I'm aware of, but you could run all of your pushes through one place in your code (either client or a cloud function), and do whatever post-push work you want to do there.  Presuming JS and advanced targeting, it could look like this:

```
function pushToInstallations(query, data) {
    var params = { where: query, data: data};
    return Parse.Push.send(params).then(function() {
        // this is the interesting part, run the installation query
        return query.find();
    }).then(function(installations) {
        var date = new Date();
        // presumes underscore, but a regular for loop works too
        _.each(installations, function(installation) {
            installation.set("mostRecentPushDate", date);
        });
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(installations);
    });
}
```

Then, wherever in your code you were building an installation query and calling push, call your new pushing function instead, like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('someColumn', someValue);

pushToInstallations(query, {alert: "some message"}).then(function(installations) {
    // these installations passed back were pushed to and updated
}, function(error) {
    // handle error
});
```